# How do I create a boxplot using ggplot2 for a gene expression data and how to normalize the given data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, normalization, boxplot

[This is the data I have of 11030 variables and I want to make a boxplot with all the data present. It would be great if someone can help me with the normalization of the data in R. I am relatively new to it. Thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIUCw.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you update the reproducible sample of your data instead of the image. The image won't help us to reproduce the sample. Run dput(head(data))  to get the structure. Refer  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: RNA-seq normalization is typically done through EdgeR or DESeq2, but you need count data for that, not decimal numbers. In DESeq2 you use the `vst()` function to normalise the data to log-scaled numbers with variance stabilised. Also, what exactly are you trying to make a boxplot of? It doesn't make sense to me to make a boxplot of every gene, not does it to make sense to make a boxplot of all genes combined in every sample. What is is exactly that you want to show?